# What is the difference between an iceserver with multiple urls and multiple iceservers?

Tags: webrtc, turn

As I understand it, IceServers can be configured when doing ICE, which is a server list. And each Server in this list can also be configured with multiple URLs.

So what is the specific difference between these two cases as follows?

```json
{
    iceServers: [
        { 
            urls: [
                "turn:aturn.com?transport=udp", 
                "turn:aturn.com?transport=tcp"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and such as the following:

```json
{
    iceServers: [
        {
            urls: ["turn:aturn.com?transport=udp"]
        }.
        {
            urls: ["turn:aturn.com?transport=tcp"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. libWebRTCs [ParseIceServers](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:third_party/webrtc/pc/ice_server_parsing.cc;l=320?q=parseiceservers) which is used in Chrome and Safari currently translates the former to the latter.